# Add textView below Map Fragment Dynamically

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have been trying to add a textview inside a linearlayout below a fragment of google maps programatically but the text view doesnt seem to get added. Here's my xml file :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/root">
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:context="com.example.burhan.googlemapsdemoapp.MapsActivity" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/mapLayout">


</LinearLayout>
```

and here's my code for adding the text view:

```java
linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapLayout);    
final TextView tv = new TextView(Map.this);

tv.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
tv.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

tv.setText("Some text");
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

Log.d("View","StackTrace");

try{
    linearLayout.addView(tv);
}catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
}
```

Comment: try calling requestlayout() on the root LinearLayout after you add the TextView

Comment: why that try/catch block?

Comment: was trying to find if there were any exceptions...totally out of frustration! @user1779222

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout to this, and remove your dynamic add of TextView.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
android:id="@+id/root">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    tools:context="com.example.burhan.googlemapsdemoapp.MapsActivity" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:id="@+id/mapLayout">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="whatever"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```